# Using Google AdWords API for the Keyword Tool using PHP and Curl?

Tags: php, curl, google-ads-api

Does anyone know a quick way to get keyword ideas using the AdWords API using CURL. The URL should be something like https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/o/v201101/TargetingIdeaService?wsdl, but I'm not sure what parameters I should include or if this is even possible.

I know there is a PHP library available from Google to use, but I just wanted to know if there is something quick and dirty.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No, there is no quick & dirty way. AdWords API uses SOAP & Oauth 2. You need about 5 tokens or accounts to access it. They make it very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is absolutely nothing out there that I'm aware of that is remotely "quick and dirty".

Your two options (that I'm aware of) are as follows:

1. You apply for the Google Keyword Tool API program. The admission process requires that you have a good reason for signing up for the API and they require some proof (client request, live website offering SEO service that you provide, etc). Usage will incur fees, which are unknown to me since I never made it past the first stage.
2. You scrape the Keyword Tool. Google has done a great job obfuscating it and continually make changes so this is difficult. If you succeed, please let me know as there are many people who are interested in the data.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do quick and dirty keyword research I'd recommend using http://keywordtool.io/api - it  provides the data from Google autocomplete.

If you don't have Google Adwords API access yet, it's going to be time consuming process to get one.